# CSS overriding doesn't seem to work even with !important

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, slider

With the CSS

```
.page-id-5094 .bg-white-base .wrap-x .inside mini {
    max-width: auto !important;
}
```

I can't get the slider to take the fullwidth. The WordPress test page that I am trying to add the slider in is at the link below. Please point out why it is not taking any effect.

https://dev-packed-with-purpose.pantheonsite.io/slider-test-page/

Comment: Did you mean `.inside.mini`?  Also, is `auto` even valid for [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)?

Comment: Yes, is it not correct. Please visit the page so you know it better.\

Comment: I tried that also but it didn't work

Comment: *"Please visit the page"* - Please provide a [mcve] here in the question to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Since this page is delivered by WordPress, I'm trying to override the css. I don't have HTML that I created for this page. I used the layouts supplied by the advanced Custom fields plug-in

Comment: Where do you set the width?

Comment: In customization under Appearance in WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this your have html

```
<div class="inside mini">
</div>
```

so, in css like this

```
.page-id-5094 .bg-white-base .wrap-x .inside.mini {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
.page-id-5094 .bg-white-base .wrap-x .mini {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

or

```
.page-id-5094 .bg-white-base .wrap-x .inside {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: have a nice day